# Loading and showing high resolution images on mobile devices

Tags: android, iphone, ios, ipad, mobile

I'm looking for a framework or a solution of loading and showing high resolution images on mobile devices where being able of viewing them in their native resolution is compulsory. Scaling is optional.
I'm talking about resolutions reaching over 2000x1000 pixels.

10x for your kind help BR

Answer (score 1):

Without going into much detail you could probably use a `TextureRegion` with [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) to display certain parts of your image on the screen.

I even think there's an example on the wiki you could use.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apple's [PhotoScroller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080) example. I have successfully used it with images over 100 megapixels.